# My code keeps getting killed for memory issues

Tags: shell, memory-leaks, beautifulsoup, out-of-memory

So I wrote this script to go over a large wiki XML dump and pull out the pages I want.  However, every time I run it the kernel displays 'Killed' I'm assuming this is a memory issue after reading around but I'm not sure where the memory problem is in my script and if there were any tricks to reduce the virtual memory usage.

Here is my code (I assume the problem is in the BeautifulSoup partition as the pages file is pretty small.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

pages_file = open('pages_file.txt', 'r')

#Preprocessing
pages = pages_file.readlines()
pages = map(lambda s: s.strip(), pages)
page_titles=[]
for item in pages:
  item = ''.join([i for i in item if not i.isdigit()])
  item = ''.join([i for i in item if ord(i)<126 and ord(i)>31])
  item = item.replace(" ","")
  item = item.replace("_"," ")
  page_titles.append(item)


with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as wiki:    
  soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki)
wiki.closed
wiki_page = soup.find_all("page")
del soup
for item in wiki_page:
  title = item.title.get_text()
  if title in page_titles:
      print item
  del title
```

Comment: Here is the dmesg error I got                                                      [15206379.618471] Out of memory: Kill process 16548 (python) score 465 or sacrifice child
[15206379.620207] Killed process 16548 (python) total-vm:52133996kB, anon-rss:50032968kB, file-rss:0kB

Answer (score 2):

If the XML file is very big, you might be able to use Soup Strainer to process it.  See documentation at http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document.  In your case, you could get away with searching simply for `title` tags, given that you check each against a list.

Note you shouldn't need to use 'del' statement like that, but I presume you did this in an attempt to solve the error?